# Repeat function every day to check time

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I want to create IOS application by Html and javascript.

I have this toggle switch ، I want to call `RepeatTask` when the user click on checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" check="setInterval(RepeatTask,86400000);" >
```

when it calls the function I want to repeat the this function every day and check time like-

```
function RepeatTask(){
    var date = new Date(); // Create a Date object to find out what time it is
    var hours=timeEdit.substring(0, 2);
    var minutes=timeEdit.substring(5, 7);
    if(date.getHours() === hours && date.getMinutes() === minutes){ // Check the time
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Can someone help me !

Comment: Your question is bit unclear. Please edit with more details and also mention the exact requirement.

Comment: Is this data being saved anywhere? If this is solely a client side function this most likely wont work because if the browser window is closed your functions wont be executed.

Comment: what is `timeEdit`? What error you are getting?